# What is this tiny kanji?

Tags: words, kanji, writing-identification

I have found this kanji in a PC novel

[image]

It is so small that I tried to draw it

[image]

The context is the following:

> "(Kanji)廃棄物処理場
>
> 区の(Kanji)廃棄物処理場

So it's related to "garbage process", but is also used in

> 区だよ区!
>
> でも区の(Kanji)は...

(and here it is used as "address" or "place" based on the context, it can be related to a dump place or something similar?)

Comment: Those imgur links are worthless...

Comment: You mean the link or the content? If the latter, I apologize for being horrible at Paint, and the original is there if someone want to download it or zoom it or something. I can upload to other site or try to draw again.

Comment: @istrasci Ridiculously small, but not worthless...

Comment: By the way, although a literate speaker can probably read this kanji just fine, you should never ask character identification questions without the surrounding linguistic context (if there is a context).  The way we recognize characters (or letters, etc.) uses the linguistic information from the surrounding context as well as the character itself, so it can make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is small, but I think it says

> 核廃棄物処理【かくはいきぶつしょり】
>   nuclear waste disposal

核 translates to "nuclear", for example 核兵器 "nuclear weapon", etc.